# Connecting functions to work together and quantity count

Tags: javascript, object, events

I started a practice project for an "e commerce app" and I need help, I dont know how to approach this project the best way.I tried using constructors, didn't work out now I'm writing it with regular functions and I'm stuck. Can anyone give me some tips what should I do and how do I approach this project.

I am also stuck with adding quantity count to my code, no matter what I do quantity is always 0 or 1.
Should I refactor everything and make it all small functions that somehow work together or what, I'm confused.

```
let products = [];
let cart = {};

function Shop() {
  addProduct(
    document.querySelector("#add"),
    document.querySelector("#pName"),
    document.querySelector("#price"),
    document.querySelector("#desc")
  );
  createCart();
}

function addProduct(eHandler, name, price, desc) {
  eHandler.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!products[products.length]) {
      products[products.length] = {
        name: name.value,
        price: price.value,
        desc: desc.value,
      };
    }
    renderProducts(products, document.querySelector("#shop-items"));
  });
}

function renderProducts(products, container) {
  let { name, price, desc, quantity = 0 } = products[products.length - 1];
  const template = `

        <h1>${name}</h1>
        <h3>${price}$</h3>
        <p>${desc}</p>
    
    `;
  const itemContainer = document.createElement("div");
  itemContainer.innerHTML = template;
  itemContainer.classList.add("shop-item");

  const orderButton = document.createElement("button");
  orderButton.classList.add("shop-order-button");
  orderButton.setAttribute("name", name);
  orderButton.innerHTML = "Add to Cart";
  orderButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    cart[name] = {
      name,
      price,
      quantity: quantity++,
      addToCart: cartHandler => {
        cartHandler.innerHTML += `<p>${name}, ${price}<p>, ${quantity}`;
      },
    };
    orderButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    cart[name].addToCart(handleCart());
    console.log(cart);
  });

  itemContainer.appendChild(orderButton);
  container.appendChild(itemContainer);
}

function createCart() {
  let cartContainer = document.createElement("div");
  cartContainer.classList.add("updateCart");
  document.body.prepend(cartContainer);
  return cartContainer;
}

function handleCart() {
  return document.querySelector(".updateCart");
}

Shop();
```

Comment: Please create a demo in stackblitz or here using stacksnippet

Comment: here https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nfa8wr?file=index.js

Comment: now can you please tell me he problem, since it is not clear from the question

Comment: I am trying to add quantity in cart to add +1 evey time i click the same element in "shop" and I would like to know how to refactor all of this to be more reusable.